# Width equal to height, problems with padding

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I tried to make some kind of a gallery made out of blocks. So I searched for the question: "How to set height equal to width". After trying it out it worked. But the method they explained was the famous `'pading-bottom in % = width in %'`.  And of course since there is a padding my image can't be placed inside the box.

Is there a way to place the image inside the box?

If any of you know the answer or another method, please let me know.

```css
.imagebox{
border: 1px solid red;
width:25%;
padding-bottom:25%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="imagebox">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="imagebox">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  

 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Attach fiddle for more understanding.

Comment: The trick is to use absolute position on the image (or a child div holding the image) inside the the parent block.

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css

Comment: just added a fiddle replicating my situation

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you very much! I can work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works OK, but then the `img` adds height to the `div`, so you should make `div` relative, and img `absolute`:

```css
.imagebox {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.imagebox img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagebox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/?a=1">
</div>

<div class="imagebox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/?a=2">
</div>

<div class="imagebox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/?a=3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and answer! I fixed it.

Comment: if this answerd your question, please mark it as a correct answer, with the "V" sign. 10x